# What method does Python 2 use to print tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, self-reference, cpython, python-internals

Python's `print` statement normally seems to print the `repr()` of its input. Tuples don't appear to be an exception:

```
>>> print (1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> print repr((1, 2, 3))
(1, 2, 3)
```

But then I stumbled across some strange behavior while [messing around with CPython's internals](https://gist.github.com/garcia/8063145). In short: if you trick Python 2 into creating a self-referencing tuple, printing it directly behaves completely differently from printing its `repr()` / `str()` / `unicode()` representations.

```
>>> print outer   # refer to the link above
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
... many lines later ...
((((((((((Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError: stack overflow
>>> print repr(outer)
((...),)
>>> print str(outer)
((...),)
>>> print unicode(outer)
((...),)
```

So what exactly is `print` doing? In an attempt to answer this question myself, I referred to the language reference:

> ### [6.6. The `print` statement](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)
>
> `print` evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting object to standard output (see below). If an object is not a string, it is first converted to a string using the rules for string conversions.

And the rules for string conversions are:

> ### [5.2.9. String conversions](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/reference/expressions.html#string-conversions)
>
> A string conversion is an expression list enclosed in reverse (a.k.a. backward) quotes:
>
> ```
> string_conversion ::=  "`" expression_list "`"
> ```

But enclosing `outer` in back quotes has the same result as calling `repr()` and friends. No dice. So what the heck is `print` actually doing behind the scenes?

(Interestingly, the behavior is "fixed" in Python 3: printing a self-referencing tuple gives the ellipsis-truncated form.)

Comment: I got `struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295` when I tried your code.

Comment: You're probably running a 64-bit build of Python. Replacing both instances of 'I' with 'Q' should, in theory, fix that.

Comment: Now it fails at `c_outer[inner_index:inner_index+4] = struct.pack('Q', id(outer))` with `ValueError: Can only assign sequence of same size`

Comment: Try replacing `+4` with `+8`. **EDIT:** I've updated the linked Gist and it should now work on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: +1 it failed with segmentation fault, after printing a huge chunk of `(`.

Comment: This is most likely a bug. Why don't you report this?

Comment: I doubt it's significant enough to warrant a fix, given that the only way to reproduce it is by messing around with pointers. I'm more interested in why there are apparently two behaviors for stringifying tuples, one of which breaks under a very obscure corner case.

Comment: It's already been reported and rejected as `not to be fixed` in Python 2.  `http://bugs.python.org/issue1069092`

Comment: That bug report deals with many tuples that are deeply nested inside one another, not a single tuple nested inside itself. The stack overflow in my example is really just a side effect of the actual bug.

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked closer.  A stack track shows that the stack overflow results from a recursive call loop between `internal_print` (around `object.c:315` and `tupleprint` (around `tupleobject.c:253`).  The problem of recursive container reprs was fixed in Python 3.2:  http://bugs.python.org/issue9840

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find out what is actually happening by disassembling python bytecode.

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(compile('print outer', '<string>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (outer)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

And reading the source for the underlying opcodes.

[PRINT_ITEM](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/ceval.c#l1752) eventually reaches this block of code:

```
else if (Py_TYPE(op)->tp_print == NULL) {
    PyObject *s;
    if (flags & Py_PRINT_RAW)
        s = PyObject_Str(op);
    else
        s = PyObject_Repr(op);
    ...
}
else
    ret = (*Py_TYPE(op)->tp_print)(op, fp, flags);
```

This means that `__str__` or `__repr__` will be called only if object's type does not have a tp_print function. And tupleobject has [one](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Objects/tupleobject.c#l241).

If you want to understand the internals of CPython the best way is to read the source code. I recommend a series of tutorials on [python internals](http://tech.blog.aknin.name/category/my-projects/pythons-innards/), it explains everything you must know to fully understand the output of python dis function.